# Android: Set user-agent on WebView not working

Tags: android, android-webview, user-agent

I have a WebView on an activity where I load some urls. The point is that some of them I want to load the desktop version of them and not the mobile so I'm trying to define a user agent from a desktop version browser. On the emulator is working fine but when I'm trying it on my phone divice is not working and is loading the mobile version. Below is my snippet code from onCreate() method from the activity. Any ideas?

**onCreate()**

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
if(usera.equals("pc")) {
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");
}else {
     webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
}
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Print in log your 'usera' before 'if(usera.equals("pc"))'

Comment: I did that and it says pc... I also add and a log inside the if to see if it goes in and also print the user-agent from the webView after the set and it says that the user agent is what I defined. But still is not working.

Comment: Try without 'if'. Directly 'webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");'

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: May be you update (recreate) webView in another places